# After fall bicycle feels really slippery

Tags: tire

I fell pretty bad this winter, and after that (even now without a trace of snow where I live) I feel the bike really slippery, mostly the front wheel. Riding on slightly uneven surfaces makes me feel I'm going to slide to the side, and side wind also feels I'm losing control of the bike.

Bike is less than a year old and I only commute with it, no long distances.

Could it be a technical problem or a confidence issue?

Comment: Have you checked your tyre pressure?

Comment: I think it's about the same as I always ride. I'll try pumping them though.

Comment: I don't think anyone can give you an answer that's sure to be right, but if your bike is in good mechanical condition then I think it's probably just confidence. Your mind is leery of falling again, so it's hyper-aware of every little twist and turn. The only way to cure that is by riding your bike. Success builds confidence.

Comment: The road surface probably isn't completely dry, which won't help, but it probably is just confidence.  Tiredness can also make the bike feel like it's handling badly so don't underestimate the effects.  Do consider what your fall was like - did you hit something (before the ground) - could you have have bent something (e.g. fork, wheel).  I got knocked off by another cyclist and my handlebars were several degrees off.  A more subtle knock might just leave it feeling funny, and combined with nerves and damp roads could explain it.

Comment: Check that the handlebar isn't twisted slightly, and that your seat is properly aligned.  If these get out of alignment the bike feels "weird".

Comment: Another thing to check is that one of your wheels (likely the rear) hasn't "tacoed".  Spin the wheels and watch the rim near one of the stay/fork and make sure the rim remains at an even distance from the stay and doesn't move in and out as the wheel turns.  I once had a wheel "taco" due to a slide such as you describe.  On rim brakes the bike usually becomes unrideable, but not always, and the wheel could be petty badly bent on a disk brake wheel without causing rubbing.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

For the most part, whenever the front wheel on a bike skids or slides at speed, the rider wipes out. The only people that manage to stay up right are either very lucky or have reflexes that Jedi warriors would be envious of.

If you are riding after a recent fall and feel like your front wheel is *sliding*, but you are still upright, then you have some sort of post-crash confidence hit, and are interpreting any motion as being an imminent crash.

Check that your fork isn't damaged, handlebars are aligned, and that your wheels are true, but otherwise just keep riding and rebuild your confidence.

Comment: And make sure the tires are pumped up hard.

Answer (score 0):

I fell and broke my ankle in 2011 and it took me a year to get back in the grove. I rode for another year and fell again this time requiring brain surgery. Both accidents happened getting on or off a good trail system.  I'm just getting back into it again and like some said above, the only cure is riding again.

As for your bike, take it to a good bike shop and tell them what's happening and tell them to check it out thoroughly. You could have nothing wrong at all or a bent/warped something as has already been suggested.  Your bike should not feel squirmy or have any wiggle in it unless you are riding on soft or loose roadbed.

Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

I ride bike in Minnesota winters in ice and snow. The key is to have proper equipment. With my carbide studded tires, glare ice feels like concrete. Also if you have your tires overinflated, you'll have less traction in the winter. In the winter or slippery conditions always use less front brakes. Always do the M check on your bike. Pick up your front and spin the tire. Is it wobbly? Then check the head bearings, then handle bars, then seat and finally rear wheel. Any lose bearings or quick releases will make the bike handle badly.

I am sure you are a bit shell shocked, but I also suspect your rig isn't dialed in...